# Java SwingGUI is broken

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

My code is very simple, really there is no problem in writing my code. I'm getting the file not found error as an error, but I'm 100% sure the file path is correct, I've checked hundreds of times. There are no other errors. Some different image upload methods give no error but as a result, the image never appears.

ChatGPT: can't fix.

Image: 16x16, .png, 1.72KB
Compiler IDE: Eclipse

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame window = new JFrame("JavaTests");
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(true);
        window.setSize(800,600);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);

        try {
            File imageFile = new File("icon.jpg");
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
            label.setSize(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
            label.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
            label.setOpaque(false);
            window.add(label);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("LOG: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Path File:
[image: PATH FILES]

Error Code
[image: ERROR CODE]

Comment: The path would be correct if your program ran from the src folder. It does not.

Comment: Images are *resources* : Better to load your files/images as resources:
[Netbeans](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/78-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-netbeans)
[Eclipse](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)

Comment: g00se When you mean source, are you talking about the directly decoded image?

Comment: The [current directory](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/91-find-the-current-directory-in-java)
is a concept you need to know

Comment: I didn't understand your comment question btw

Comment: The current directory I found is: "eclipse-workspace\JavaLessons" so I edited "File imageFile = new File("src/icon.png");" but still no picture. The error is still the same.

Comment: See: [Loading Images Using getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html#getresource). The file must then be found on your "classpath".

Comment: camickr I tried this before. "getClass().getResorce("bla bla")" didn't work, still gave the same error.

Comment: *so I edited "File imageFile = new File("src/icon.png");* Well I wasn't actually suggesting that as a solution. It should be done with `getResource`. Real programs don't run from IDEs, for one thing

Comment: `getClass().getResource("/icon.png");`

Comment: Is your "classpath" set up correctly? You need to have your "bin" directory on the classpath. I don't use an IDE so I don't know how to do it in Eclipse

Comment: camickr Correct, Thanks for the information, but I'm not doing a serious project, I'm testing.

Comment: I've been struggling for 2 days now and I just had a look and this time it happened. I don't know what caused it, but it's probably "The path would be correct if your program ran from the src folder. It does not." i fixed my code based on this comment. So it worked, so solution: " new File("src/icon.png");" I didn't add src/ before.

Comment: Actually, just noticed your code is attempting to access "icon.jpg" but you questions shows the file name is "icon.png".

Comment: Yes, changing "icon.jpg" to "src/icon.png" fixed it. Thank you to everyone who replied.

Comment: (1-) No, you should not be using "src". The image is also located in the "bin" director with all your other class files. Did you not read the tutorial link I provided? It shows common directory structures to use so you don't have a problem. The image belong in a directory structure with your class files.

Comment: **There is no guarantee that icon.png exists,** because you don’t know what the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory) of your Java process will be.  Your code is broken because it relies on an unsafe assumption about the current directory.  The Class.getResource method is designed to address this safely and reliably.

Comment: *"Yes, changing "icon.jpg" to "src/icon.png" fixed it"* - No, it's just masked the bigger problem.  Don't use `File`, in your context, it's looking for a file in the CURRENT WORKING DIRECTORY, which IS NOT you "src" directory AND your "src" directory will NOT exist when your export the program.  Your image is now an EMBEDDED image, you MUST use `Class#getResource` to load it.

Comment: When you post your next question about why you can't load your images when your program is exported out to a jar, we will point you back to this question

Answer (score 0):

First mistake:
Your screenshot shows the file name "icon.**png**",
but in your Java code you try to load "icon.**jpg**".

Second mistake:
When you specify

```
File imageFile = new File("icon.png")
```

then the file is assumed to be in the *current* directory,
which in your case is your project directory
(i.e. the directory also containing your `src` and `bin` folder).
But that is not where your image file actually is.

A safe way to load the image file from the same directory
where your `.class`file is (i.e. the `bin` folder), is like this:

```
URL imageUrl = main.class.getResource("icon.png");
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
```

And be aware calling `getResource(...)` will give `null`
if the file is not found.